# When function is meant to return true, nothing is returned

Tags: python

So I've written two functions, isdiv which returns whether x is divisible by y without any remainders and check_is_divisible which takes in two numbers and should return true if the first number is divisible by all the positive integers smaller than or equal to the second number. Except that for some reason check_is_divisible doesn't return anything when it should return true. It returns false when it should and doesn't seem to be stuck in any infinite loops so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
def isdiv(x,y):
    return x%y == 0

def check_if_divisible(value,largest_divisor):

    if isdiv(value,largest_divisor):
        
        if (largest_divisor == 1):
            return True
        
        check_if_divisible(value,(largest_divisor-1))

    else:
        return False
```

Comment: tl;dr - you're missing `return` next to the `check_if_divisible` call

Comment: BTW, the body of `isdiv` can (and should be) written as `return x%y == 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make the recursive call, you need to forward the result. Otherwise, the recursive return value is discarded and `None` is returned by default.

```
def check_if_divisible(value,largest_divisor):
    if isdiv(value,largest_divisor):
        if (largest_divisor == 1):
            return True
        return check_if_divisible(value,(largest_divisor-1))
    else:
        return False
```